# Using two different columns in a Where statement depending on if one is empty

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

I've currently got a `WHERE` clause in a SQL string that looks like this:

```
CmdTxt = CmdTxt + "Where FA.CSE_LAN = '" + UID + "' ";
```

It eventually culminates in a call to Oracle:

```
OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand(CmdTxt, connection);
cmd.Connection = connection;

cmd.CommandText = CmdTxt;
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
OracleDataAdapter da = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);

da.Fill(dt);
```

What I now need to do is change that WHERE logic, so that it first looks at a column called `FA.BUILD_CSE_LAN`. If that has a value, it will use that column in the `WHERE` clause.

If it doesn't have a value, it will use the column `FA.CSE_LAN` in the `WHERE` clause.

How can I do this? I'm using C# code-behind in an ASP.Net environment against an Oracle 12c database, if any of that is important.

Comment: `UID  = "' OR 1 = 1;--";`

Comment: You need to [use parameterized queries](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7505808/557445). Your existing code, as Will pointed out, can leave you vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.

Comment: While I agree parameterized queries are important, assuming UID is either a UniqueID or UserID, generally those don't come from string inputs. Potentially userID but then that would actually be a user name.

Comment: I agree with parameterized queries, but it's an intranet and this is the way they do things here.  I'm more concerned with the syntax than the variables.

Comment: It may not be as important due to the trusted nature of the users, and depending on the source of the values, but it is always better practice. Though I admit even in the code we use in my workplace we sometimes just put values right into the string, but those values came from a database already.

Comment: BTW, UID is set in code and is read from WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name, so there really is no chance for injection.

Answer (score 1):

I am no expert on oracle but I would try something like this.

```
CmdTxt = CmdTxt + "Where FA.BUILD_CSE_LAN = @UID  OR ( FA.BUILD_CSE_LAN IS NULL AND FA.CSE_LAN = @UID)";
```

That way it if your build field is null, no value, it checks the other one.
And declare `@UID` as a parameter on your command to avoid injection or special character issues.

Answer (score 1):

This doc on Oracle might help: [NVL](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm) or [COALESCE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions023.htm#SQLRF00617) could help here.

```
CmdTxt = CmdTxt + "Where NVL(FA.BUILD_CSE_LAN, FA.CSE_LAN) = '" + UID + "' ";
```

or

```
CmdTxt = CmdTxt + "Where COALESCE(FA.BUILD_CSE_LAN, FA.CSE_LAN) = '" + UID + "' ";
```